# I receive an error when attempting to .map through an array from an api

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, axios

I currently am trying to iterate through an array that I got from an api.

My current code is :

```
displayEmailList = () => {
    let emails = [...this.state.info.emails]

    return emails.map(email => {
      console.log(email)
    })
  }
```

This is my state and async function :

```
state = {
        info: '',
        domain: 'homeadvisor.com'
    };

    async componentDidMount() {
        let info = await axios.get(
            `https://api.hunter.io/v2/domain-search?domain=${this.state
                .domain}&api_key=76056a7300959044150346f9d8dd3c5d6faef844`
        );

        this.setState({
            info: info.data.data
        });
    }
```

The Error message I receive is:

```
TypeError: this.state.info.emails is not iterable
```

However if I console.log(this.state.info)

I can clearly see that I have an array of emails

[image]

Comment: Probably the map statement is running before the API fetch.

Comment: Update the question with the response

Answer (score 3):

Your initial value of `info` in your `state` is an empty string.

Initialise your state like this:

```js
state = {
    info: {email: []},
    domain: 'homeadvisor.com'
}
```